# Getting "react is not defined" in React18 and webpack 5.88.1

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, react-dom

I have been trying to come out from CRA and use React18 and webpack 5 in my react application. I tried many things but none of them seems to be solving.
[image: This Error]

I tried nearly every answer from web but nothing worked and i am still getting this error. This is my first time not using CRA so kind of stuck in end loop.

Here is my webpack config

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    mode: 'development',
    externals: {
        react: 'react'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js',
    },
    target: 'web',
    devServer: {
        port: '3000',
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
        },
        open: true,
        hot: true,
        liveReload: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
        modules: ['bower_components', 'node_modules', path.resolve('./src')],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 100000,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html')
        }),
    ]
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env",["@babel/preset-react", {"runtime": "automatic"}]]
}
```

and index.js in src folder

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "__globalStore/store";


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <App />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I did putting externals in webpack , changing plugin , writing reactDom before , nearly every answer could have mentioned. I am using React 18.2 and webpack `5.88.1`

Comment: You use `react` as externals, so how did you include `react` library in your project?

Comment: @LinDu, Externals was not working for me as I tried different things, I found the issue on Git Hub and shared the solution for that too.

Answer (score 0):

Is anyone still confused, I have solved by using this solution . I went through this while I was finding the solution. Adding react in `External` didn't helped me with getting react o work without importing it.
So I had to add a plugin in `webpack.config.js`.

I just added this

```
const webpack = require('webpack'); // at top

 plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            "React": "react",
        })
    ]
```